# First milliseconds of conditional rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, next.js

I want to prevent my app from displaying the wrong case of a conditional rendering (before retrieving the data) during the loading phase.
Let me explain, when I'm logged in (the user data is stored via useContext hook) and I refresh my page: automatically the page displays the forms for log in but it disappears a second after that my PWA understands that I'm logged in as it retrieves the user data. How can I prevent that little timing issue ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you share a minimal code example?

Comment: Do you have server-side rendering?

Answer (score 2):

It should actually be quite easy to keep from rendering it, until you **know for sure** that it needs to be shown. Something like this:

```
{this.state.needToShowLogin &&
    <LoginForm />
}
```

In the init part (e.g. class constructor) you start with this value being `false`. Then change it if & when you decide that it needs to be set to `true`.